# It is possible to convert flutter code to flutterflow?

Tags: flutter

I am learning flutterflow at the moment. I came across Flutter and I was wondering, could I use Flutter code, and add it to my project and finish it with flutterflow?

Answer (score 4):

for flutterflow you can only add your flutter code  either in custom widgets , custom functions or custom actions.